# Are there any ferries between Okinawa and China?

Tags: japan, china, ferries, okinawa

I know there are ferries between China and Japan and I know there are no ferries between Okinawa and Taiwan.

But I'm not sure whether I'm missing something when I try to look for ferries between anywhere in China and anywhere in Okinawa.

Are there any ferries operating such routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as usual not directly.

There are ferries operating from Shanghai to Kobe and Osaka, by multiple companies

- [Japan China International Ferry Company](http://www.shinganjin.com/time_table_e.php)
- [Shanghai Ferry Company](http://www.shanghai-ferry.co.jp/english/kouro.htm)

and from Qingdao to Shimonoseki by:

- [Orient Ferry Company](http://www.orientferry.co.jp/schedule.html) - And [in English](http://www.orientferry.co.jp/homepage%20english.pdf)

From Osaka you can definitely [catch a ferry to Naha](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2355_01.html) from Shimonoseki I am not so sure but you can probably find domestic ferries to Osaka and catch one from there to Naha or get to Kagashima and do the same.